# Testing Android code with JUnit and the JDK

Tags: android, eclipse, junit, java, junit4

I'm writing some POJO tests for my Android code.

I want to run them locally with the JDK (not with Dalvik on the emulator) - for speed, JUnit 4, Mockito, and being able to run headless without a device - so I have a separate "Java" project in Eclipse.

If the method I'm testing happens to reference anything from the Android SDK, e.g. `android.util.Log`, the test fails - this makes sense because `android.jar` isn't in the classpath. To reproduce I have this test case:

```
public class FooTests {
  @Test
  public void testFoo() {
    android.util.Log.d("x", "y");
  }
}
```

If I add `android.jar` explicitly to the test project's classpath, I get exceptions like

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
  at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:7)
  at com.example.FooTests.testFoo(FooTests.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  ...
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Is there a way to make the code work without mocking out every last bit of Android SDK dependency? Perhaps a mocked-out `android.jar` already exists?

**EDIT**: For now I ended up wrapping classes like `android.util.Log` and injecting them into the instances, for classic IOC-based testing. Scott's PowerMock suggestion is my next step when I'll need it.

**LATER EDIT**: [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no mocked out android.jar that I know of.  I use Powermock to mock everything out.  One thing you can do to help with the heavy mocking is to make your extended android classes like activity, fragments, broadcasters, etc. thin and have them delegate to pojo classes.  You could make a risk based decision not to isolation unit test the android extended classes, and instead integration unit test them via the android testing framework or something else like Robotium.

For true isolation unit testing in Android, for me unit testing on the java jvm mocking all out all collaborating classes is the best way to go.

Comment: +1 Good points, I'll try PowerMock. Any relevant links beyond https://sites.google.com/site/androiddevtesting/ ?

Comment: I haven't seen that link before but it's excellent, thanks for sharing. I do find myself referencing the Powermock "usage" section on their website quite often when trying to figure out the various ways that are needed for mocking out android jar classes: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I wanted to test simple POJOs locally.
Specifically, my code wanted to use android.util.Base64.
What I ended up doing was to use the SDK to install the Android 4 sources, and copied the android.util.Base64 class to my project.
Surprisingly enough, this worked.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up creating a "Base64Encoder"-type interface, implementing it with `android.util.Base64` in the app and with `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` in the tests :) It would have been awesome to simply have a JAR with all the library code intact, and just the framework bits that are tied to a running environment stubbed out.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I wanted to test simple business logic locally.
Specifically, my code uses `android.util.SparseArray<E>`.

I tried 3 different approaches to make it testable with junit outside android.

- In my business logic I created an interface and attached it to `MySparseArray<E>` that inherits from `SparseArray<E>`. In the junit-test I re-implemented the interface using `HashMap<Integer, E>`. This works but in the long run this is to much work to make business logic unit-testable if other `android.*` are required.
- As suggested by @Tal Weiss I added the android java sources of the required classes: `android.util.SparseArray.java` that uses `com.android.internal.util.ArrayUtils.java`. This works, too but I don't like to add more android sources, especially if there are much more dependencies
- I downloaded a stub free binary `android.jar` for an old android 2.2 from http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1 and included it as lib into my junit-java-project. This jar contains only classes for namespaces `android.*`, `com.android.*`, `dalvik.*` and `framework.base.*`. This works too.

Currently I succeeded to avoid using `android.*` classes except `SparseArray<E>` in my business layer and has no dependency to Context, Activity or Service. I could have used `HashMap<Integer, E>` in the android-business layer instead of `SparseArray<E>`.

Comment: I've tried https://github.com/bjoernQ/unmock-plugin to use SparseArray in JUnit tests and it worked but after adding keepStartingWith "dalvik.system." in the unMock section.

Answer (score 1):

unmock-plugin could help https://github.com/bjoernQ/unmock-plugin. In my case it works with SparseArray.

Answer (score 0):

Won't [the embedded android/junit tests](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html) do what you want?

Comment: So far I've used this to run tests with the InstrumentationTestRunner on an emulator or on an actual device. It's appropriate when I want to test an activity or a service, but not when I just want to test some plain old logic unrelated to the Android platform. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the first bullet talks about 'plain old junit' testing, for your 'plain old logic' :)

Comment: Sure, but as far as I can tell I either have to run them on an emulator or device, or get "Stub!" exceptions same as now :(